# Automatically create Tag objects when creating an object, Django REST Framework

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework

I have the Task model:

```
class Task(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=1000, blank=True)
    completed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    date_created = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    due_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    date_modified = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
    tasklist = models.ForeignKey(Tasklist, null=True, related_name='tasks', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(TaskType, related_name='tasks')
```

And class TaskType (tag in other words):

```
class TaskType(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

I also have TaskSerializer:

```
class TaskSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    tags = serializers.SlugRelatedField(many=True, slug_field='name', queryset=TaskType.objects.all())

    class Meta:
        model = Task
        fields = '__all__'
        read_only_fields = ('date_created', 'date_modified', 'tasklist')
```

When I create a Task, to add some tags I need to create them in appropriate view firstly, but I want them to be created on the fly.
So in case of editing the task, I added `update` method:

```
def update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    instance = self.get_object()
    tag_names = request.data.get('tags', [])
    for tag_name in tag_names:
        tag, created = TaskType.objects.get_or_create(name=tag_name)
        instance.tags.add(tag)

    serializer = self.serializer_class(instance=instance, data=request.data)
    serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
    serializer.save()
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

It works fine, but when I add new tags when creating a new task it fails (400 bad request):

```
{
    "tags": [
        "Object with name=%new_tag% does not exist."
    ]
}
```

I figured out that it would be a good way to create appropriate tag object before creating Task with it, so I added `perform_create` method:

```
def perform_create(self, serializer):
    print('debug')
    tag_names = self.request.data.get('tags', [])
    for tag_name in tag_names:
        tag, created = TaskType.objects.get_or_create(name=tag_name)

    list_id = self.kwargs.get('list_id', None)
    try:
        tasklist = Tasklist.objects.get(pk=list_id)
    except Tasklist.DoesNotExist:
        raise NotFound()
    serializer.save(tasklist=tasklist)
```

It doesn't help me, actually I am not sure if perform_create method at least is called, because I see no print('debug') in the console (when I create Task with an existing tag I see it).
So the question is how to change perform_create method to be able to create fresh Tasks without creating Tag firstly.

Answer (score 1):

First, you don't need to manually `add` tags in your view methods. The serializer will do it for you.

Second, the `update` method is used when you *update* your model. When *creating* you need to override `create` method, `perform_create` works, but happens too late:

```
def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    tag_names = request.data.get('tags', [])
    for tag_name in tag_names:
        TaskType.objects.get_or_create(name=tag_name)

    serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data)
    serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
    serializer.save()
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

Third, once you've created new tags, call `super().*method*` and let the framework do the work for you:

```
def update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    tag_names = request.data.get('tags', [])
    for tag_name in tag_names:
        TaskType.objects.get_or_create(name=tag_name)

    return super().update(request, *args, **kwargs)

def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    tag_names = request.data.get('tags', [])
    for tag_name in tag_names:
        TaskType.objects.get_or_create(name=tag_name)

    return super().create(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

There is also `partial_update` method you need to add if you are planning to use PATCH method, so you might be better off overriding your serializer's `to_internal_value` method instead of each of those:

```
class TaskSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    tags = serializers.SlugRelatedField(
        many=True, slug_field='name', queryset=TaskType.objects.all())

    class Meta:
        model = Task
        fields = '__all__'
        read_only_fields = ('date_created', 'date_modified', 'tasklist')

    def to_internal_value(self, data):
        for tag_name in data.get('tags', []):
            TaskType.objects.get_or_create(name=tag_name)
        return super().to_internal_value(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try editing your view like this,

```
def update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    instance = self.get_object()
    tag_names = request.data.get('tags', [])
    serializer = self.serializer_class(instance=instance, data=request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        new_object = serializer.save()
    if new_object:
        for tag_name in tag_names:
            tag, created = TaskType.objects.get_or_create(name=tag_name)
            new_object.tags.add(tag)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

Comment: Basically your method is for editing the Task (put method), I need to specify new tags when creating new Task.

Comment: how are you thinking to specify the tags?? are you sending the tag_names through request.data['tags']?? I dont quite understand what your requirement is..

Comment: I send POST to a task view like this: {"tags": ["tag1", "tag2",...], "name": "name", ...}